# Seeding a database with a one to one relationship in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having issues seeding a database with two models i a one to one relationship.

**db/seed.rb**

```
 auser = User.create!(email: "example@test.org",
          password:              "example",
          password_confirmation: "example", 
          admin: true )
         # profile_attributes: [name: "Example Test",
         # street: "75 Barracks Rd",
         # city: "Water,
         # sex: "Male"]
         # )
auser.profile.create!( name: "Example Test",
           street: "75 Barracks Rd",
           city: "Waterloo",
           state: "AW", 
           zipcode: "23455",
           #sex: "Male" 
           )

 99.times do |n|
   name  = Faker::Name.name
   email = "example-#{n+1}@railstutorial.org"
   street = Faker::Address.street_address
   city = Faker::Address.city
   state = Faker::Address.state_abbr
   zipcode = Faker::Address.zip_code
   password = "password"
   n.User.create!(email: email,
           password:              password,
           password_confirmation: password )
     # profile_attributes: [name: name, sex: sex, street: street, city: city, state: state, zipcode: zipcode])  
   #  n.profile.create!( name: name, street: street, city: city, state: state, zipcode: zipcode ) 
  n.each { |user| user.profile.create( name: name, street: street, city: city, state: state, zipcode: zipcode) }
end
```

If i use `profile_attributes` as commented out in the seed.rb file, i get the error `NoMethodError: undefined method "with_indifferent_access" for #<Array:0x86e46a0>` but if i leave it the way it currently is, i get the error `SyntaxError: C:/Sites/NouveauMiniOlympics/db/seeds.rb:37: syntax error, unexpected '\n', expecting =>`

**user params in user controller **

```
  def user_params
            params.require(:user).permit(:id, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, profile_attributes: [:name, :street, :city, :state, :zipcode] )
  end
```

Comment: You could always do: `Profile.create(user_id: auser.id)` to assign the relationship

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with_indifferent_access` is a Rails ActiveSupport method which takes a hash and returns a `HashWithIndiffentAccess` which put simply does not care if you use symbols or strings to access its properties.

```
irb(main):002:0> hash = { foo: "bar" }
=> {:foo=>"bar"}
irb(main):003:0> hash["foo"]
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> hash.with_indifferent_access[:foo]
=> "bar"
irb(main):005:0>
```

So what does this mean? 
You are passing in an array when rails expects a hash.

```
profile_attributes: [name: name, sex: sex, street: street, city: city, state: state, zipcode: zipcode]
```

simplest solution is:

```
profile_attributes:  { name: name, sex: sex, street: street, city: city, state: state, zipcode: zipcode }
```

But we don't really want to type all of those variables out if we are only going to use them once!

```
99.times do |n|
  User.create!(
    email: Faker::Internet.safe_email, # "name@example.org"
    password: 'password',
    password_confirmation: 'password'
    profile_attributes: {
      name  : Faker::Name.name,
      street : Faker::Address.street_address,
      city : Faker::Address.city,
      state : Faker::Address.state_abbr,
      zipcode : Faker::Address.zip_code
    }
  )
end
```

Comment: I didn't even know you could do `[a: 1, b:  2]`. The result is `[{:a=>1, :b=>2}]`. Not really sure why you would want to do it though and why its built into the language.

Comment: Thanks @Max; the first one is suppose to be the default through which i could test out other attributes such as :admin.

Comment: Whats the problem? You just apply the same solution to  where you are creating `auser`. I'm not going to do everything for you :) Then you'll never learn.